# vba function which takes a range parameter as input and returns a range

Tags: vba, excel

I want to write a vba function which takes a range parameter as input and outputs the cell where it gets the match.

```
Function find_cell_range(slct As Range, ByVal search_name As String) As Range

    Dim rg As Range
    With Range(slct)
         Set rg = .Find(What:=search_name, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)
    End With

    Set find_cell_range = rg

End Function


Sub test_sub()

    Dim rg as Range
    rg = find_cell_range(Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight)), "Col1")
    'Some code which uses Range variable rg

End Sub
```

With this, I'm sometimes getting  `Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed` error. How should I successfully pass the range that can be used in my function?

Comment: `Range(slct)` should be just `slct`

Comment: @Slai that worked! You should post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Range()` accepts either a single string A1 reference, or 2 cell Range/String address.

```
Function find_cell_range(slct As Range, ByVal search_name As String) As Range

    Set find_cell_range = slct.Find(What:=search_name, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

End Function


Sub test_sub()

    Dim rg as Range
    rg = find_cell_range(Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight)), "Col1")

    If Not rg Is Nothing Then
        'Some code which uses Range variable rg
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. You should call it like,

```
Set rg = find_cell_range(Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight)), "Col1")
```

Comment: Please see the edited question for the full error message even after using `Set`

Answer (score 0):

You must use ***Set***:

**UNTESTED**:

```
Sub test_sub()

    Dim rg as Range
    Set rg = find_cell_range(Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight)), "Col1")
    'Some code which uses Range variable rg

End Sub
```

Comment: I have used `Set`, but I'm still getting the error (edited the question to show the full error)

Comment: @StrikeR  If **Set** failed, that means the **Find()** failed!

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand why u are calling the function in a function. Just use:

```
Sub Test()
Dim rg As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = Worksheets("Tabelle1")
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rg = sht.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Find("Col1")
End Sub
```

And now you can address `rg` like you want it from your function.

Comment: I'm writing it as a separate function for the purpose of re-usability of code

Comment: But you can do that with the function itself, why make it more complicated than its already is.

Comment: the only thing you would need to edit is `MatchCase:= True`

Comment: Its true that this function is making it complicated, but I would see it as lesson to properly write and reuse the code. The first comment on the question helped me with the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the error using its number if that's what you want:

```
Sub test_sub()
    Dim rg As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rg = find_cell_range(Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight)), "Col1")
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        MsgBox "Set range returns an error!"
        'you can exit sub, set a new range, or goto anywhere in your code
    End If
    'Some code which uses Range variable rg
End Sub
```